# Displaying one of multiple components best practices

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm currently using React and Redux, and I'm trying to find the best way  of displaying one of multiple components. That is, I have various modals set up (`<Modal-1 />`, `<Modal-2 />`, ..., `<Modal-N />`) and a variable in my Redux store describes which modal should show.

```
// store
modal: {
  name: 'Modal-8', // null or undefined --> no show
  payload: 'some data the modal might need'
}
```

An initial approach to issue would be something like

```
export default Modals ({ name }) => (
  {name === 'Modal-1' && <Modal-1>}
  {name === 'Modal-2' && <Modal-2>}
  {/*...*/}
  {name === 'Modal-N' && <Modal-N>}
)
```

Is there an efficient way of selecting to render one out of many components based on a variable/flag?

Do you suggest an alternative approach to displaying different modals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a hash table for this

```
export const Modals = {
    'Modal-1': Modal1,
    'Modal-2': Modal2,
    'Modal-3': Modal3
}
```

the way you would use this is

`const Component = Modals[name];`
and in the render return `<Component />`

---

I would strongly you rename your components, `Modal-1` is a bad naming convention and doesn't mean much to anyone. `LoginModal` `ImageModal` things like that mean a whole lot more to a developer.

Comment: Yes, my components have descriptive names, it was only for the example :)

Comment: @aryzing awesome! glad to hear that lol. I was like umm thats a weird naming convention haha